# Refactor from ES5 TO ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was given the task to refactor this code from ES5 to ES6 , I am currently learning JS and this is like an assignment I really want to complete.

You can see how I already started refactoring here, I need to use the following ES6 concepts: class, static methods, spread operator, const / let and array destructuring.

```
class LetterSequence {
    constructor () {
    }
    static createSequence (sequence) {
      const characters = sequence.split("");
      let containerString = "";
      let repeatCount     = 1;
    }
    }


LetterSequence.createSequence = function(sequence){
  const characters      = sequence.split("");
  let containerString = "";
  let repeatCount     = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
    const currentChar = characters[i];
    const prevChar    = characters[i - 1];
    const nextChar    = characters[i + 1];

    if (currentChar === prevChar){
      repeatCount++;
    }

    // If the sequence is broken, and the repeat count is greater than 1
    // add the letter and the repeat count to the return string
    if (currentChar !== nextChar && repeatCount >= 1){
      const repeats = repeatCount > 1 ? String(repeatCount) : "";
      containerString += (repeats + currentChar);
      repeatCount = 1;
    }
  }

  return containerString;
};

LetterSequence.decodeSequence = function(sequence){
  var containerString = "";
  var characters      = sequence.split("");

  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
    const current         = characters[i];
    const nextChar        = characters[i + 1];

    // If the current character is not a number, then there must be a letter after it
    if (!isNaN(characters[i])){
      // So repeat it n times, and add it to our return value
      const letters = this._repeat(current, nextChar);
      containerString += letters;
    // If the current character is a letter, and the last character is a letter, then
    // it must be a lone letter
    } else if (isNaN(characters[i]) && isNaN(characters[i - 1])){
      containerString += characters[i];
    }
  }

  return containerString;
};

// Maybe there's a function to do this in ES6...?

LetterSequence._repeat = function(count, character){
  let characters = "";

  if (count <= 1){
    count = 1;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
    characters += character;
  }

  return characters;
};

module.exports = LetterSequence;
```

Comment: What does this code do? As per the [ask] guidelines, please explain, and also make that the title of the question. Otherwise, this question is what we call a "code dump", which is frowned upon.

Comment: ["Refactoring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) has a very specific meaning. It seems like what you mean here is "rewrite" or "port" to ES6.

Comment: To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My rewrite

#### Code

```js
{
  'use strict';
  const LetterSequence = {};

  LetterSequence.encodeSequence = (sequence) => {
    let result = '';

    (sequence.match(/(.)\1*/g) || []).forEach((repetition) => {
      const count = repetition.length > 1 ? repetition.length : '';
      result += count + repetition[0];
    });

    return result;
  };

  LetterSequence.decodeSequence = (sequence) => {
    let result = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
      const parsedCharacter = parseInt(sequence[i]);
      if (Number.isInteger(parsedCharacter) && (i + 1 < sequence.length)) {
        result += sequence[i + 1].repeat(parsedCharacter);
        i += 1;
      }
      else {
        result += sequence[i];
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  console.log(
    LetterSequence.decodeSequence(
      LetterSequence.encodeSequence('aaaaabbbbcccdde')
    )
  );
}
```

```css
/* Output console formatting */
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
```

#### Benchmark

The above code executed with a speed of 133,230 ops/s ±4.14%, whereas yours at 17,562 ops/s ±4.14%, which is almost 8 times slower.
[image]

#### Remarks

- My code doesn't account for the fact that you *need to use the following ES6 concepts: class, static methods, spread operator, const / let and array destructuring*. Tips about these are further within this answer.
- `/(.)\1*/g` will match all repeating characters. One match – one group of repeated characters.

In both our codes:

- `TypeError` should be thrown if `typeof sequence !== 'string'`.
- Repeated multibyte characters such as  will not count as a sequence.
- Strings containing digits will introduce confusion and functions may not give expected results. Perhaps in such case error should be thrown as well.

---

### Remarks to your code

- There are few problems with formatting and indentation
- I would personally replace all `""` with `''`, as they – among other things – take less on-screen space, thus reducing cognitive load.
- You have few `var`s that you could replace with `let`s.
- Multiple `const`s and `let`s should be combined.
- `createSequence()` should be named `encodeSequence()` to create analogy with `decodeSequence()`.
- In those two functions from previous bullet point, order in which `containerString` and `characters` are declared is opposite.
- Entire class's content seem unnecessary.
- You are not using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- `sequence.split("")` could be declared with use of [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) as `[...sequence]`, although conversion to array is unnecessary at all. You can access each character of string just like if it was an array: `sequence[i]`.
- Regarding `LetterSequence._repeat`:

  > `// Maybe there's a function to do this in ES6...?`
  [yup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)
  .

<sub>Have a good fun with this assignment ʘ‿ʘ.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

#### `spread`-operator

You say that you need to use the [`spread`-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233956/1456376) to complete the assignment. But you actually never use it.

Instead of `split`, which is not unicode safe:

```
const characters = sequence.split('');
```

use:

```
const characters = [...sequence];
```

---

#### `repeat` a string

You can use [`.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) in ES6 to simplify your `_repeat`-function:

```
repeat = (character, count) => {
    count = parseInt(count);
    return count > 0 ? character.repeat(count) : character;
};
```

---

#### Further improvements

You use `const|let|var` inconsistently:

```
let characters = sequence.split('');
var characters = sequence.split('');
```

Try to be consistent here. Here's a good read about the three: [How much should I be using 'let' vs 'const' in ES6?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/278652/185089)